# Cannot generate native-debug-symbols file in Android studio

Tags: android

I received the deobfuscation file error from Google Play Console on my app and found out I would have to add the line in my app level `build.gradle` file

```
    android.defaultConfig.ndk.debugSymbolLevel = 'FULL
```

Before adding this line , I checked out further prerequisites and learnt that I would require `AGP 4.1+`, I already had `4.1.2` but to be safe I updated to `7.0.2`. I also installed the latest NDK and CMake versions.[image: CMake and NDK updated version installed]

After completing the prerequisites, I added the required line. Upon generating an AAB , I analyzed the AAB but there was no native debug symbol file or folder. I checked the `app\build\outputs` directory and there is no native_debug_symbols file generated there.
This is how my gradle file looks now -

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 31
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.quicklyservices.restaurants"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode 292
        versionName "2.28.2"
        ndkVersion '23.1.7779620'
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        ndk{
            debugSymbolLevel = "full"
        }
    }

    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            version '3.18.1'
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
        targetCompatibility = '1.8'
    }

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

}
```

I have tried everything mentioned in the official documentations but I cannot seem to generate the required files. It would be very helpful if I could get a solution to this.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. did you get any solution for this?

Comment: same issue, any solution?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have not received any solutions yet!